# Suppress or remove CA0068 CA warning from VisulaStudio project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a CA warning **CA0068** "Debug information could not be found for target assembly 'Myproject.dll'. For best analysis results, include the .pdb file with debug information for 'Myproject.dll' in the same directory as the target assembly".

I have tried [this Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca0068?view=vs-2017) link to clear the warning. But it was not clear the warnings. Anyone please let me know how to suppress this CA warning from my project.

Thanks,

Comment: You could try suppressing the warning using [this Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2017)

Comment: I have tried like this. <NoWarn>CA0068;0068</NoWarn>. But it is not working. Is it possible to suppress CA warning in this way